# ブランチ間のファイルをcpしたい。

Tags: git

githubでソースを管理しております。
また、ブランチは以下で運用しております。
- master
- develop
- feature/・・・

その上で、例えば、feature/Aのブランチで作成されたファイルの一部、またはすべてのファイルをfeature/Bのブランチへコピーしたい（ディレクトリごとの場合も含めて）

※現状はfeature/Bのブランチにいる状態で。

このような場合、どのようにすればいいのでしょうか？

これまでは、ブランチ間での差分を見比べて、変更があった箇所のみコピーして貼り付けるといった作業をしておりました。

イメージとしましては

$ cp feature/A feature/B ./*
みたいなことがしたいです。(コマンド一発で、ブランチ間の差分をすべてコピーしたいです)

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: `$ git merge feature/A` じゃダメってこと？

Comment: [基本的なマージをすれば良いんじゃないか](http://git-scm.com/book/ja/v2/Git-%E3%81%AE%E3%83%96%E3%83%A9%E3%83%B3%E3%83%81%E6%A9%9F%E8%83%BD-%E3%83%96%E3%83%A9%E3%83%B3%E3%83%81%E3%81%A8%E3%83%9E%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B8%E3%81%AE%E5%9F%BA%E6%9C%AC)と思うのですが、マージでは駄目な理由はなんでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

履歴が残るマージをしたくない理由はいろいろあるのでしょうから、パッチを作って適用すればいいかな？

```
git diff feature/B..feature/A > ab.patch
patch -p1 < ab.patch
```

EDIT: diffの方向をコメントに従って修正しました。

Comment: 質問文中の説明からすると、diffの方向は`feature/B..feature/A`が正しいように思われます。また、今回の件ではどうか分かりませんが、`patch`ではなく[`git-apply`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-apply)の方が便利な状況もありそうですね。

Comment: 確かにそうですね。修正します。

Answer (score 3):

[`git-checkout`のman](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout/2.6.2)が言うところの 
`git checkout [-p|--patch] [<tree-ish>] [--] [<paths>…​]`
が所望のコマンドではないでしょうか。
`feature/B` をチェックアウトした状態で、上記コマンドの`<tree-ish>`の部分に`feature/A`を指定してあげればindexに差分が入った状態になります。

> The  argument can be used to specify a specific tree-ish (i.e. commit, tag or tree) to update the index for the given paths before updating the working tree.

ということで具体的には以下のようになると思います。

```
$ git checkout feature/B
$ git checkout feature/A '*'
```

Answer (score 1):

feature ブランチ同士のマージが、ワークフロー上行儀がよくなくてやりたくない、でもマージした結果と同じものがほしい、という場合でしたら、次が実行できます。

```
# (feature/B ブランチ上で)
git merge --squash feature/A
# => worktree と index がマージした状態になるが、コミットはされない
```